# Change date format with sed or awk in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, regular-expression, date

I have file which has following format

```
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust foo
  mail: cust.foo@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 20170721085748Z
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust xyz
  mail: cust.xyz@example.com
  Account Lock: TRUE
  Last Password Change: 20181210131249Z
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust bar
  mail: cust.bar@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 20170412190854Z
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust abc
  mail: cust.abc@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 20191030080405Z
----------------------------------------
```

I want to change `Last Password Change` data format to `YYYY-MM-DD` but not sure how to do that with `sed` or `awk` or is there any other method, I can try for loop it and use `date -d` option but not sure if there is easier way to do with regex

Comment: using `date -d` will be the most robust solution and likely the most simple solution as well

Comment: Down to just YYYY-MM-DD from YYYYMMDDHHmmSS?

Comment: yess, that is correct format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all you're doing is adding two dashes, and dropping some extra characters, there's not much need for `date`.

```
$ sed -Ee 's/(Last Password Change: )(....)(..)(..).*Z/\1\2-\3-\4/' < foo.txt
...
  Name: cust foo
  mail: cust.foo@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 2017-07-21
...
```

For a stricter pattern, the dots (that match any character) could be replaced with `[0-9]` to only match digits. `\1` etc. in the replacement of course expand to what ever the patterns in parenthesis matched.

Comment: Very very very cool..... that was clever

Answer (score 4):

This is my proposal:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}Z/\1-\2-\3/' file
```

Output:

```
  Name: cust foo
  mail: cust.foo@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 2017-07-21
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust xyz
  mail: cust.xyz@example.com
  Account Lock: TRUE
  Last Password Change: 2018-12-10
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust bar
  mail: cust.bar@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 2017-04-12
----------------------------------------
  Name: cust abc
  mail: cust.abc@example.com
  Account Lock: FALSE
  Last Password Change: 2019-10-30
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow!!! that is also really good example

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this with the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F\: '$1 ~ /Last Password Change/{ OFS=":"; $2 = substr($2, 1, 5)"-"substr($2, 6, 2)"-"substr($2, 8, 2) }1'
```

Using `:` as a field separator, if the first column matches `Last Password Change` we will then use `substr` to extract the year, month, and date and replace the second column with those values in the format you desire.